# Can't deserialize XML to model

Tags: .net, xml, asp.net-web-api, soap, xml-deserialization

I can't seem to deserialize the XML without getting errors, what am I doing wrong?

**Error message:** *"There is an error in XML document (1, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <'SetPhoneStatus xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'> was not expected."*

**XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
        <SetPhoneStatus xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <msisdn>4500000000</msisdn>
            <status>Busy</status>
            <timestamp>2022-07-02 09:45</timestamp>
        </SetPhoneStatus>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Model**

```vb
<XmlRoot(ElementName:="SetPhoneStatus")>
Public Class TeliaMobileStatusModel
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="msisdn")>
    Public Property MSISDN As String

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="status")>
    Public Property Status As String
End Class
```

**Function**

```vb
    Public Function DeserializeXmlElement(Of T)(xml As XmlDocument, element As String) As T
        Try
            Dim bodies = xml.GetElementsByTagName(element)

            If bodies.Count > 0 Then
                Dim body = bodies.Item(0)

                Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(T))
                Dim result As T

                Using reader As New IO.StringReader(body.OuterXml)
                    Dim deserialized = serializer.Deserialize(reader)
                    result = CType(deserialized, T)
                End Using

                Return result
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You need the namespace attribute:

```vb
<XmlRoot(ElementName:="SetPhoneStatus", Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")>
Public Class TeliaMobileStatusModel
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="msisdn")>
    Public Property MSISDN As String

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="status")>
    Public Property Status As String
End Class
```